# Passing data to multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have 3 fragments and want to send same data to 2 of them. I wrote the below code for the first destination:

```
 val bundle = Bundle()
 bundle.putString("key",mainText.toString())
 bundle.putString("imageKey",mainImage.toString())
 val fragment = NextFragment()
 fragment.arguments = bundle
 fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.navController,fragment)?.commit()
```

Then, get the data with

```
    var args = this.arguments
    var passedText = args?.get("key")
    var passedImage = args?.get("imageKey")
```

However, for the second destination fragment, I cannot get the data. I used the same bundle as above, tried to create a new one but none of them works. I also tried to pass data using the destination

*Home Fragment -> Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2*

and

*Home Fragment -> Fragment 2*

What may be the problem?

Comment: `R.id.navController` indicates that you might be using the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/) - is that correct? You should **never** be using a `FragmentTransaction` when using the Navigation Component, but should be following the [guidance on passing data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data).

Comment: I guess yes, I am using Nav. Component. I saw it from a tutorial and then continue with it. The tutorial was this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COZ3j8Dwlog

However, I am new to android and do not know where to find the problem in the documentation.